# Survivorship bias in Bonds

Tags: bonds

Bonds have default risk categories like AAA, BBB, etc. Bond funds often choose bonds based on these categories.

With ETFs and Mutual funds, there is a level of survivorship bias because the fund is ranked based on historic returns.

Does a similar historical survivorship bias exist in ranking bond funds? For example, if a company/nation is upgraded to A from B, then will the bonds that used to have a B rating all be upgraded, their price jump up, etc thus making certain bond ETFs return look artificially high?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Survivorship bias applies to hypothetical (backtested) portfolios, not real ones. An ETF (or mutual fund) reports the return attributable to its holdings (stocks or bonds) *while it held them*. A bond ETF holding "A" bonds may buy a bond recently upgraded from "B", but any price jump associated with the upgrade is already reflected in the purchase price and does *not* contribute to the ETF's reported return.

At a higher level, survivorship bias can affect the evaluation of *families* of ETFs and mutual funds. If underperforming funds are closed, the surviving funds will show atypically good performance. But your question does not seem to be about this.